# How to remove an extra empty line when formatting a <ul> unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a vertical menu in the left side of the screen.
I created the effects using an online CSS button generator and use it to format my `<li>` tags in the menu.
The problem is that in Firefox and in Chrome I get an extra "Button" at the beginning of the list and pushes the first menu tag to the right. I don't have enough points yet to post a print screen.
Under IE the blank menu doesn't appear but the corners and shadows don't work. Right now that doesn't bother me.

here is the list from the HTML file:

```
<div id="myButton">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" >Text</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

In the CSS formatting:

- First I move the `<ul>` to the left and take out the bulleting form the list
- then I create the style for the `<li>` when you hover over the mouse and when you push the button.

And here is the CSS file:

```
#myButton ul{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width:185px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

 #myButton li a{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #007dc1), color-stop(1, #0061a7));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007dc1', endColorstr='#0061a7',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#007dc1;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #124d77;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 0px #154682;
}

#myButton li a:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0061a7), color-stop(1, #007dc1));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0061a7', endColorstr='#007dc1',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#0061a7;
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
}
#myButton li a:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: In many occasions you can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) instead of screens

Comment: Hm... can't recreate problem in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8qd9j00/

Comment: <a hreflang="ro">  what is this? Remove it from source, and everything will work fine. So, problem is not in your presented code - problem is in bad HTML formatting. (if you view source in Firefox - errors will be marked with red color, it helps :)

Comment: Just needed to close it. It was put there for search engine region optimization.

Comment: where is that element, the provided markup contains no such element .. what r u all talking about ?!

Comment: I posted a direct link to my page but I removed it so it is not considered as promoting. Already changed the page script anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code 
`<a hreflang="ro">` in your head.

Remove that, and try.

should be `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ro"/>`

you dont want anchor tag in your head.

Answer (score 0):

as other users suggested I also tried jsfiddle and the code works fine.

The problem was the `<a hreflang="">` from the `<head>` element that was missing the `</a>` and because of that it was creating an empty element.
Found out when inspecting the page using source code viewer and the first `<href>` was red!